# How can i find Poincare's paper about algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to read Poincare's paper about the algebraic topology how can I find his paper in English?

Comment: Are you talking about Analysis Situs?

Comment: Try a web search on "Stillwell Poincare". . For a discussion of a new approach to basic homology and homotopy,  see http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brouwer-honor.pdf .

Comment: thanks that is what i want

Answer (score 1):

It's linked in the wikipedai article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9. In the references at the end of the page is a section "Poincaré's writings in English translation". Of course his 1895 Analysis Situs, in which he introduces the fundamental group, may be his most famous collection.

Comment: How can I get the others' links?

Comment: There are links to many others. Not all are freely available online. The list includes refernces to the books in which they appear, and you could track these down. Many will be available to you if you have journal access at some academic institution.